# Why am I getting uncaught reference error with this Backbone Marionette code?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, marionette

I was going thru a Backbone Marionette tutorial....Everything was going well until I started adding code to instantiate a collection with a model.    I'm using Marionette 2.4.2 and Backbone 1.2.1.  Here is what I get in Chrome console:

*Uncaught ReferenceError: firstName is not defined  VM40:6*

Below is the entire html, css, and js code.  It's a very simple app thus far.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset='utf-8'>
      <!-- Always force latest IE rendering engine or request Chrome Frame -->
      <meta content='IE=edge,chrome=1' http-equiv='X-UA-Compatible'>
        <!-- Use title if it's in the page YAML frontmatter -->
        <title>Welcome to Tracker</title>
      </meta>
      <meta content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0' name='viewport'>
      <meta content='blah content' name='description'>
      <title>Landing Page &ndash; Layout Examples &ndash; Pure</title>
      <link href='http://yui.yahooapis.com/pure/0.6.0/pure-min.css' rel='stylesheet'>
      <link href='https://cdn.rawgit.com/konpa/devicon/89f2f44ba07ea3fff7e561c2142813b278c2d6c6/devicon.min.css' rel='stylesheet'>
      <!--[if lte IE 8]>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://yui.yahooapis.com/pure/0.6.0/grids-responsive-old-ie-min.css">
      <![endif]-->
      <!--[if gt IE 8]> ><! <![endif]-->
      <link href='http://yui.yahooapis.com/pure/0.6.0/grids-responsive-min.css' rel='stylesheet'>
        <!-- <![endif] -->
        <link href='http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.4.0/css/font-awesome.css' rel='stylesheet'>
          <!--[if lte IE 8]>
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="../stylesheets/marketing-old-ie.css">
          <![endif]-->
          <!--[if gt IE 8]> ><! <![endif]-->
          <link href='./stylesheets/marketing.css' rel='stylesheet'>
            <!-- <![endif] -->
          </link>
        </link>
      </link>
    </meta>
  </head>
  <body class='index'>
    <div class='header'>
      <div class='home-menu pure-menu pure-menu-horizontal pure-menu-fixed'>
        <a class='pure-menu-heading' href='/'>Tracker Home</a>
        <ul class='pure-menu-list'>
          <li class='pure-menu-item pure-menu-selected'>
            <a class='pure-menu-link' href='#'>Home</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class='splash-container'>
      <div class='splash'>
        <h1 class='splash-head'>Tracker</h1>
        <p class='splash-subhead'>
          Lorem Ipsum...
        </p>
        <p>
          <a class='pure-button pure-button-primary' href='#projects'>Start Here</a>
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class='content-wrapper'>
      <a name='projects'></a>
      <div class='content'>
        <h2 class='content-head is-center'>Current Candidates</h2>
        <div class='pure-g'>
          <div id="current-candidate-app" class='l-box pure-u-1 pure-u-md-1-2 pure-u-lg-1-4'>
            <h3 class='content-subhead'>
              <i class='fa fa-book'></i>
              Candidate list 
            </h3>
            <p id="current-candidate-container">
            </p>
            <script type="text/template" id="current-candidate-template">
              <li><%- firstName %> <%- lastName %></li>
            </script>
          </div>
      </div>
      <div class='content ribbon l-box-lrg'>
        <h2 class='content-head content-head-ribbon is-center'>Finished Candidates</h2>
        <div class='pure-g'>
          <div class='l-box pure-u-1 pure-u-md-1-2 pure-u-lg-1-4'>
            <h3 class='content-subhead'>
              <i class='fa fa-pencil-square'></i>
              BWP
            </h3>
            <p>
              Lorem Ipsum
            </p>
            <p>
              One of my posts,
              <a href='http://www.binarywebpark.com/testing-elasticsearch-in-your-rails-4-application/' target='_blank'>Testing Elasticsearch In Your Rails 4 Application</a>
              was featured in
              <a href='http://rubyweekly.com/issues/233' target='_blank'>Ruby Weekly #233</a>
            </p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class='content'>
        <h2 class='content-head is-center'>Skills</h2>
        <div class='pure-g'>
          <div class='l-box pure-u-1 pure-u-md-1-2 pure-u-lg-1-4'>
            <h3 class='content-subhead'>
              <i class='devicon-rails-plain-wordmark colored'></i>
              Rails
            </h3>
          </div>
          <div class='l-box pure-u-1 pure-u-md-1-2 pure-u-lg-1-4'>
            <h3 class='content-subhead'>
              <i class='devicon-ruby-plain-wordmark colored'></i>
              Ruby
            </h3>
          </div>
          <div class='l-box pure-u-1 pure-u-md-1-2 pure-u-lg-1-4'>
            <h3 class='content-subhead'>
              <i class='devicon-javascript-plain colored'></i>
              JavaScript
            </h3>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class='footer l-box is-center'>
        Copyright 2015-Present by Bruce Park
        <div class='pure-g'>
          <div class='l-box pure-u-1 pure-u-md-1-2 pure-u-lg-1-3'></div>
          <div class='l-box pure-u-1 pure-u-md-1-2 pure-u-lg-1-3'>
            <a class='no-underline' name='contactme'></a>
            <h3 class='contact-color'>
              Contact Info:
              <a class='no-underline' href='https://twitter.com/bpark0' target='_blank'>
                <i class='fa fa-twitter'></i>
              </a>
              <a class='no-underline' href='https://github.com/treble37' target='_blank'>
                <i class='fa fa-github'></i>
              </a>
              <a class='no-underline' href='http://www.binarywebpark.com/contact/' target='_blank'>
                <i class='fa fa-envelope'></i>
              </a>
            </h3>
          </div>
          <div class='l-box pure-u-1 pure-u-md-1-2 pure-u-lg-1-3'></div>
        </div>
        <p>
          Crafted with
          <a href='https://middlemanapp.com/'>Middleman</a>
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <script src="./javascript/jquery.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    <script src="./javascript/json2.js"></script>
    <script src="./javascript/underscore.js"></script>
    <script src="./javascript/backbone.js"></script>
    <script src="./javascript/backbone.localstorage.js"></script>
    <script src="./javascript/backbone.marionette.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      var CandidateManager = new Marionette.Application();
      //models
      CandidateManager.Candidate = Backbone.Model.extend({
        defaults: {
          firstName: "firstName-placeholder",
          lastName: "lastName-placeholder",
          phoneNumber: "phoneNumber-placeholder"
        }
      });

     //collection
      CandidateManager.CandidateCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
        model: CandidateManager.Candidate
      });

      //views
      CandidateManager.CandidateView = Marionette.ItemView.extend({
        template: "#current-candidate-template",

        events: {
          "click p": "alertPhoneNumber"
        },

        alertPhoneNumber: function() {
          alert(this.model.escape("firstName") + ": " + this.model.escape("phoneNumber"));
        }
      });

      CandidateManager.CandidateCollectionView = Marionette.CollectionView.extend({
        tagName: "ul",
        childView: CandidateManager.CandidateView
      });

      CandidateManager.on("before:start", function() {
        var CandidateManagerRegionContainer = Marionette.LayoutView.extend({
          el: "#current-candidate-app",

          regions: {
            main: "#current-candidate-container"
          }
        });
        CandidateManager.regions = new CandidateManagerRegionContainer();
      });
      CandidateManager.on("start", function() {
        var candidates = new CandidateManager.CandidateCollection([
          {
            firstName: "Alice",
            lastName: "Smith",
            phoneNumber: "123-4568"
          },
          {
            firstName: "Rob",
            lastName: "Williams",
            phoneNumber: "223-4568"
          }
        ]);
        var currentCandidateView = new CandidateManager.CandidateView({
          collection: candidates
        });
        CandidateManager.regions.main.show(currentCandidateView);
      });
      CandidateManager.start();
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

As it turns out, it was a silly error:

I was accidentally instantiating the ChildView

```
var currentCandidateView = new CandidateManager.CandidateView({
          collection: candidates
        });
```

when I should have been instantiating a Collection view:

```
var currentCandidateView = new CandidateManager.CandidateCollectionView({
          collection: candidates
        });
```